# Is there any C/C++ Runtime Enviorment for Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, executable, c

I am a C/C++ developer. I would like to run my .exe programs on my computer (which only has Ubuntu on it). I would like to know if there are any C/C++ Runtime Enviroments out there.

Comment: Question on unstable alpha releases are off topic according to our [faq].

Comment: I removed the 13.04 references because it is irrelevant for the question. I think this should not be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with C++ at all. Windows and linux binaries are different and you wont be able to run a .exe natively. There are compatibility libraries that can run most windows programs but at the cost of some performance. The most widely used one is [wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Install the build-essential package using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

You can then use 'g++' to compile your source code so it can be run on that machine. If you have a Makefile you can use command 'make' which is also installed by the above package.

Comment: I have codeblocks so all I want to do is run executable files from linux

Comment: Like Wolfer said to run an .exe file on ubuntu you would have to install wine or an equivalent. However if you have the source code it makes more sense to just compile the code on the linux machine to get a native binary for linux/unix platform.